# Can I call Console Integration Toolkit Functions from an Object Specific Quick Action?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, publisher-action, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I am currently working on a service console feature where I want to embed a Lightning component in a Visualforce page using the Lightning Out library. I need to pass a case record id to the Lightning component by retrieving the case id from the primary tab in the console.

I've been able to achieve this before using the following code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:slds />
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/40.0/integration.js"/>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <style>
        .slds-form-element__label {
            font-size: 0.8125rem !important;
        }
    </style>
    <body class="slds-scope">
        <!-- Page div used to inject Lightning component -->
        <div id="assetManagerDiv"></div>
    </body>

    <!-- Script that uses the Lightning javascript library to inject a lightning component into the VF page div -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(function(result){
                // Execute Lightning out functions
            });
        }());
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

However, when I run this from within a publisher quick action on the case object, the integration toolkit function does not execute. I do not see any error messages occurring or anything like that.

Are there any work arounds for this or is it not possible to use the integration toolkit library in a publisher action?

Comment: are you using this in Lightning console .

Comment: @Raj_SFDC No it's just the classic console.

Comment: Do you happen to have Development Mode turned on for your user? This can interfere with toolkit operations in publisher actions in the console as it creates nested iframes that break the cross-frame communication the toolkit needs to work. Info about the dev mode here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_dev_mode.htm&type=0